# What's the right way to keep my program from ending while waiting on events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have an app that sets some events and needs to wait for those events to occur before exiting.  What's the best way do this?  I understand that Thread.Sleep is a poor choice for various reasons including the fact that it won't even be able to process events if it's sleeping.  I obviously don't won't to waste cpu cycles with a while loop that does nothing.  So what's the simplest way to prevent a console app from exiting for an indeterminate amount of time so it can process events as they are raised?

Ultimately this is going to be a service which will make this a non-issue but right now on my first iteration I'm just testing out some of my code in a console app before I go through the trouble of making it into a real service (haven't made a service before so I'd like to make sure my code is solid so as not to complicate the next step).  As I'm writing this I just realized I could have just tested it in a WinForms app instead and that would solve my problem, duh.

Comment: What sort of events are you talking about, and what sort of application? It would really help if you could give us more context.

Comment: Take a look to [ManualRaiseEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)

Comment: Are you after something similar to the MSDN example for WaitHandle.WaitAll here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet Put a little more info up there.  I started to answer your question more fully a couple times but was having trouble not writing a book about it.  I may give it another shot after I eat though :)

Comment: I've built on [this](http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/) to write services that can also be run, and debugged, as console applications.

Comment: @user92546 Thanks, after reading that I realized I'm definitely making this more complicated than need be :)  If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built on [this](http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/) to write services that can also be run, and debugged, as console applications.

The "make it more complicated" approach didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx).  This allows you to block while waiting for the event to be set, without sleeping.  The main routine of your console application can call `WaitOne()` on the `ManualResetEvent`, which will block.  When your routine finishes, just call `ManualResetEvent.Set()` to allow the console application to shut down.

If you need to wait on a collection of events, [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent) is another option.  You can call `AddCount()` and `Signal` to increase and decrease the count as needed.

Comment: I thought this was going to do it, but I don't think this lets the app continue to handle further incoming events while it's blocking... at least it didn't appear to in my test just now.

Comment: @BrandonMoore If you're dealing with other threads, it should work fine.  This will block the main thread, and the other threads should handle setting your event.

Comment: Actually the main thread just dispatches new threads to handle incoming events.  So would doing this on the main GUI thread of a WinForms app keep it from being able to process control events (like a button click event)?  It seems that it would to me from my testing so far, but maybe I just have something else wrong in my code as I've written a lot more code than I normally do without incremental testing as I go.

Comment: That is, I was using the analogy of a WinForms app to say that if it wouldn't work there then it wouldn't work for what I'm doing either, and it doesn't seem like it would from what I can tell so far.

Comment: @BrandonMoore A console app doesn't have a message pump, so you need to block to keep it from shutting down.  In a WinForms app, the window itself keeps it from shutting down the message pump.  We'd need more details to give you an idea of how to make it work for you.

Comment: Right, I understand that.  What I mean is:  Does this approach allow the main thread to continue processing events while it's waiting for ManualResetEvent.Set() to be called or is it more like having it sleep?  The idea isn't 'just' to keep the thread from dying while a particular process finishes, but to allow the main thread to continue dispatching new threads as events are raised.  My 1st test seemed to indicate it was like sleeping but I may have had something else wrong.  In any case, I think User92546's comment is the best fit for my situation. +1 for a good idea anyhow.

Comment: @BrandonMoore This will block until the event is set.

Comment: <Sigh> :)  I apologize, but for some reason I'm having a really hard time communicating my question so let me try one last time.  I think maybe part of the problem could be that you assume I know more than I do about what it means to block.  When it's blocking, does that mean the thread will do absolutely nothing until it's signalled to resume, or does that mean it could still process an event if one was raised?

Comment: @BrandonMoore There's no way for the "thread" to process an event, unless there is some form of message loop which finds it.  If you're blocking a thread waiting on a ManualResetEvent, it will do nothing at all (just hang that thread's processing) until the MRE is set.  Normally, if a thread is waiting on an event coming from some other source, the thread will actually happen on a threadpool thread or other thread, though, so blocking the main thread is fine...